# How to make a Wii game with SDL?

Tags: sdl2, wii

I am trying to find a way to create a Wii game using SDL2, but I can't find any tutorials on how to do it. How can I use SDL2 to build and privately distribute a Wii game without hacking/modding the Wii?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot, the Wii does not have a supported environment for developing software, except by licensing with Nintendo and probably renting hardware.

Any private development done is generally on a hacked Wii, there is a SDL port for the Wii if you want to go that route: http://wiibrew.org/wiki/SDL_Wii but it is an incomplete port.